# Executable jar file from a Maven JavaFX project shows multiple errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx, executable-jar

I created a simple JavaFX project using Maven. When I run it in Eclipse it runs smoothly. But once I create an executable jar file, it won't run.

**The Errors:**

If I do "Export" -> "Runnable JAR File Export" -> by "Library handling:" I selected "Extract required libraries into generated JAR":

- Once I click "Finish", multiple warnings appear stating (multiple times)

```
    duplicate entry: module-info.class
```

In addition, when I try to run "java -jar exe.jar" in my terminal this error is printed:

```
    Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

If by "Library handling:" I select "Package required libraries into generated JAR":

- I can export it without any issue, but when running it with "java -jar exe.jar" in my terminal again this error is printed:

```
    WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @2cebc0b2'
    null
    Exception in Application start method
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2541)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
        at main.Main.loadScene(Main.java:25)
        at main.Main.start(Main.java:17)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
```

I consulted many Stack Overflow pages but couldn't get it to run. Can anyone help me?

These are my classes and the pom.xlm file:

The Main class:

```
    public class Main extends Application {
    
        ApplicationController controller = new ApplicationController();
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Scene root = loadScene("Application.fxml", controller);
            initAndShowStage(stage, root, "Laboratory");
        }
    
        private static Scene loadScene(String fxmlPath, Object controller) throws IOException {
            System.out.println(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fxmlPath));
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fxmlPath));
            loader.setController(controller);
            Parent parent = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            return scene;
        }
    
        private static Stage initAndShowStage(Stage stage, Scene root, String title) {
            stage.setScene(root);
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setFullScreen(false);
            stage.show();
            return stage;
        }
    
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            launch(args);
        }
    
    }
```

The ApplicationController class:

```
    public class ApplicationController {
        @FXML
        private Label something;
        @FXML
        private Button somethingButton;
    
        private boolean step = false;
    
        // Event Listener on Button[#somethingButton].onAction
        @FXML
        public void setLabel(ActionEvent event) {
            if (this.step == false) {
                this.something.setText("Hello there!");
                this.step = true;
            } else {
                this.something.setText("Begin!");
                this.step = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The pom.xml file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>TestNEW</groupId>
        <artifactId>TestNEW</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
    
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <dependencies>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                <version>19-ea+9</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                <version>19-ea+9</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: Executable jars for containing JavaFX framework code are not recommended.  See the [packaging section of the JavaFX tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for alternatives.

Comment: Each module must be in a separate JAR so you cannot create a single JAR containing your code and the dependencies as it was possible in Java 8 and lower or without using the [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).

Comment: @Tavernkeeper Could you solve this issue? I have a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75126162/creating-executable-jar-in-intellij-java-18-javafx-18-maven-project-warning).